# Check multiple multiple similar conditions with && inside if

Tags: c#, if-statement

row has many columns, some of them are of list from. I need to check the following only for list type columns:

```
if(row.columm1.Count == 0 
      && row.column2.Count == 0 
      && row.column3.Count == 0 
      && row.column4.Count ==0)
{
    //do something
}
```

How can I shorten the if-statement

Comment: Why do you have two identical if statements?

Comment: Put them into an array or list (or pass as `params` to a method). Then `list.All(z => z == 0)`.

Comment: Or, if none of them can be negative, check the sum for zero

Comment: Use Reflection to find all fields of type List with name columnX and call property Count on each. Then use list.All

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to alter this. The simplest is perhaps:

```
if(row.Columns.All(col => col.Count == 0)){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `.All()` not `Any()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Sum()` as well

```
//This will add count of Columns then it will check with 0
if(row.Columns.Sum(col => col.Count) == 0)
{
   //Your business logic
}
```

Comment: I guess I`d accept that as an answer, although it does obscure what you are looking for ever so slightly: Someone else reading the code might see it adding all the column values together, as opposed to checking each of them for a non-zero value, and then stopping. Otherwise, nice and simple answer though (sorry for the nitpicking :) )

Comment: @Kjartan, Yeah totally agree with you, I just answered as an alternative to `All()`. I would like to add here, `All()` is efficient than `Sum()`, because whenever condition of `All()`  will fail, it will not iterate for rest of the elements.
but `Sum()` will store addition of all counts and then it will check condition

Comment: @Kjartan, I added why `All()` is efficient than `Sum()` in my comment.